# Padding time series for (auto) prediction with keras

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, keras, padding

I have 3 time series, A, B and C that are defined by 30 time steps. I want to build an LSTM that given receiving as input the values of A, B from time step 1 to 30 and the values of C from time step 1 to time step 10, predict the values of C for the remaining 20 time steps. In other words I have to build an LSTM that deals with sequence inputs of different size (30 and 10). My idea is to pad (e.g. using 0s) the input time series C so that I can have 3 sequences of the same size and use a standard LSTM.

```
A1, A2, A3, ... A28, A29, A30 -->
B1, B2, B3, ... B28, B29, B30 -->  LSTM --> C11, C12, ..., C30
C1, C2, C3, ... 0,   0,   0   -->
```

Technically, this would work, however, from a conceptual point of view is this correct? Will the LSTM be enough smart to forget about the padding?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably various architectures that would work for this problem, but since it sounds like you have a fixed input size of `30+30+10 = 70` I would suggest using a standard feedforward network that takes `70` input features, has one or more densely-connected hidden layers, and outputs `20` values corresponding to the missing values of `C` you want to predict.

In `Keras` this might look like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, input_dim=70))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(300))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

If you have problems with gradients during training try adding `BatchNormalization` layers after `ReLU`, and if you are getting overfitting trying reducing the number of hidden layers and/or adding `Dropout` after `ReLU` and `BatchNorm`.

Especially for this relatively small and more importantly *fixed* input size, there is no need to use sequence models like an `LSTM`. They are more difficult to work with, and often only worth it when you input is not of fixed size.

If you find you really need an architecture that models local time features you could try a `convnet` with a `30x3` input shape with `1D` convolutions to model local time dependencies. In this case you could zero-pad `C` as you suggest.

EDIT: @TitusPullo has mentioned in chat that he tried [This example](https://gist.github.com/jkleint/1d878d0401b28b281eb75016ed29f2ee) of a `CNN` for multiple output timeseries prediction.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! I am new to deep learning...so why is LSTM not worthy when dealing with sequences of fixed input? Thanks

Comment: LSTMs are harder to train for various reasons. They are more sensitive to initialization, they are more likely to suffer from vanishing/exploding gradients, they require more computational resources, etc. You should absolutely try a simpler architecture first. You won't typically need a recurrent architecture unless your inputs are varying in size, very long, or have strong time/sequence dependent behavior. But even if the last case is true I would still try 1d convolutions with fixed size input first.

Comment: Would a 1d convolution works even with multiple inputs/outputs? That is, what if I have 4 input time series and I have to predict the future values 2 of them (in the same scenario as illustrated, where for the 2 that I have to predict I have less information).

Comment: For inputs yes, try putting them in different channels as I suggested in my answer, and for outputs just add more output units. The NN network doesn't need to know explicitly that these are separate sequences.

Comment: Do you know what your error function is by the way? Do you have any special requirements beyond minimizing the error of each element in the output sequence individually?

Comment: No, the two sequences are potentially correlated but I want to minimse the errors on both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160343/discussion-between-titus-pullo-and-imran).